# TensorFlow Object Detection API and utils module

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-2012

I am just starting with TensorFlow and came across the [TensorFlow Object Detection API tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I have followed the installation steps outlined in the first section, created a new conda virtual environment (within Visual Studio 2017) and installed `TensorFlow` using `pip`. Also I have installed the packages listed in the other sections.

This are the imports taken from here: [Detect Objects Using Your Webcam](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/camera.html)

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
import cv2

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

However it can't find the a package/module called `utils`. Unsurprisingly trying to import it fails with:

```
>>> from utils import label_map_util
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

**So what kind of module is this and where can I get it from?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the root directory of Object Detection API ( `...\models\research\object_detection` ) to `PYTHONPATH` by:

`export PYTHONPATH=\path\to\models\research\object_detection\:$PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 1):

You can also install the object detection api into your python/conda environment using

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

This will make sure that your conda environment finds the packages automatically. The setup.py file is in the models/research folder.